# Save gganimate animation as mp4 file

Tags: gganimate

Is there a way of saving the movies produced with `ffmmeg_renderer` or `av_renderer` as separate files? I always get theme embedded as data in the html file.

Answer (score 7):

Using the example from @Roman I would use `library("av")` instead:

```
p <- ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp)) + 
    geom_line(size = 2, colour = 'steelblue') + 
    transition_states(Month, 4, 1) + 
    shadow_mark(size = 1, colour = 'grey')

b <- animate(p, duration = 20, fps = 20, renderer = av_renderer())
anim_save("output.mp4", b)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't [provide a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example):

```
p <- ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp)) + 
    geom_line(size = 2, colour = 'steelblue') + 
    transition_states(Month, 4, 1) + 
    shadow_mark(size = 1, colour = 'grey')
a <- animate(p, renderer = ffmpeg_renderer())

anim_save("animation.mp4", a)
```